# ViewPager FragmentPagerAdapter only updates last fragment onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a `ViewPager` hosted in a fragment that hosts two `ListFragments` that are populated by a `Cursor` returned from an SQLite query. I recently added a spinner to my Action Bar that will allow the user to sort the lists in the `ViewPager`. However, every time the spinner is selected, only the second list is sorted even when the first list is currently displayed. It seems like the `ViewPager` is not keeping track of the currently displayed `ListFragment`.

I have tried overriding `getItemPosition` in my adapter and using n`otifyDataSetChanged`, but that doesn't help. I tried caching the position of the current active fragment in `onAttach()` also to no avail. I also tried using an `OnSortChanged` interface implemented by my adapter to try and recreate the `ListFragments`. I'm truly at a loss here. Here is my current code:

My main fragment:

```
public class BeerMenuFragment extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beer_menu_fragment, container,
            false);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.beer_pager);

    pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());
    return view;
}

private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return (new BeerMenuAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
}
}
```

My `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class BeerMenuAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final int NUM_ITEMS = 2; 

public BeerMenuAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getPageTitle(int)
 */
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return BeerListFragment.getTitle(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return BeerListFragment.newInstance(position);
}
}
```

And finally, the `ListFragment`:

```
public class BeerListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements
    OnNavigationListener {
private static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";
private static final String KEY_SPINNER = "ab_spinner";
private IconicAdapter adapter;
private static final String[] LABELS = { "Newest First", "Oldest First",
        "Alphabetical" };
private Context ctxt;
private int mShowItems;
private Cursor data;
private boolean synthetic = true;

static BeerListFragment newInstance(int position) {
    BeerListFragment frag = new BeerListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return (frag);
}

static String getTitle(int position) {
    String header = "Draft";
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        header = "Draft";
        break;
    case 1:
        header = "Bottle";
        break;
    }
    return (header);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * android.support.v4.app.ListFragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater
 * , android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_fragment, container,
            false);

    ctxt = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctxt)
            .getReadableDatabase();

    SherlockFragmentActivity activity = getSherlockActivity();
    ArrayAdapter<String> show = null;
    ActionBar bar = activity.getSupportActionBar();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        show = new ArrayAdapter<String>(bar.getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LABELS);
    } else {
        show = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LABELS);
    }

    show.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(show, this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(KEY_SPINNER));
    }

    data = getBeerMenuDbData(db, mShowItems);

    // set up list adapter
    adapter = new IconicAdapter(ctxt, data);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return (result);
}

private Cursor getBeerMenuDbData(SQLiteDatabase db, int showItems) {
    String order;
    String WHERE;
    switch (showItems) {
    case 1: // Oldest First
        order = DbContract.BeerEntry.COLUMN_MODIFIED + " ASC";
        break;
    case 2: // Alphabetical
        order = DbContract.BeerEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " ASC";
        break;
    default: // Newest first
        order = DbContract.BeerEntry.COLUMN_MODIFIED + " DESC";
        break;
    }
    String[] COLUMNS = { DbContract.BeerEntry._ID,
            DbContract.BeerEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
            DbContract.BeerEntry.COLUMN_MODIFIED };
    WHERE = "serving='" + getTitle(getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1))
            + "'";
    return db.query(DbContract.BeerEntry.TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, WHERE, null,
            null, null, order);
}

class IconicAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    IconicAdapter(Context context, Cursor data) {
        super(context, data, 0);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String dateString = cursor.getString(2);
        String[] dateArray = new String[3];
        TextView beerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.beerName);
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drinkDate);
        RatingBar rb = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

        beerName.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        if (!dateString.isEmpty()) {
            dateArray = dateString.split("-");
            date.setText(dateArray[1] + "/" + dateArray[2] + "/"
                    + dateArray[0]);
        } else {
            date.setText(dateString);
        }
        rb.setRating((float) Math.random() * 5.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.beer_club_list_item, parent, false);
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onDestroy()
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ((CursorAdapter) getListAdapter()).getCursor().close();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    if (synthetic) {
        synthetic = false;
        return true;
    }

    mShowItems = itemPosition;
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctxt)
            .getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor newData = getBeerMenuDbData(db, mShowItems);
    adapter.changeCursor(newData);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(KEY_SPINNER, getSherlockActivity()
            .getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Out of curiousity, log the calls to `onNavigationItemSelected`, and see if it is being called for both of your instances of `BeerListFragment`, or just one instance. My hunch is that when you call `setListNavigationCallbacks` for your 2nd `BeerListFragment`, it overwrites the callback of the first one, so the 1st doesn't get the callback to sort it's data, while the 2nd one always does.

Comment: @steven, I logged as you suggested, and I only get one call to 'onNavigationItemSelected' and it is only for the 2nd 'BeerListFragment', even when the 1st fragment was showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem is that you are calling `bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(show, this)` inside of your `BeerListFragment`s. When your 1st `BeerListFragment` is created in your `ViewPager`, it sets itself as the callback for the navigation selections. Then, when your 2nd `BeerListFragment` is created (`ViewPager`s resumes pages to the left and right of the currently visible page), it sets itself as the callback for the navigation selections, and **overwrites** the 1st `BeerListFragment`, which now will no longer get the `onNavigationItemSelected` callback.

This all results with the behavior you are seeing, the last `BeerListFragment` to call `bar.setListNavigationCallbacks` will be the **only** one to receive the `onNavigationItemSelected` callback. This is why only the 2nd `BeerListFragment` is being sorted.

To solve this, I would recommend you do a few things:

1. Manage setting the callback for the navigation selections in the `BeerMenuFragment`, and pass the results to the children `Fragment`s that are in "alive" (in `onResume`). You will need to use one of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-viewpager) in order to do so.
2. Store the the latest sort option applied, and check in `onResume` of each `BeerListFragment` to see if its sort matches, and if not, apply the sort.

This will guarantee that all of your sorts are applied to all of your pages in the `ViewPager`, whether they are displayed or not at the time of the sort being applied.

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Steven for the help. I used the `getRegisteredFragment` method you mentioned in the "answers here" link and then set up a `OnSortOrderChangedListener` interface to tell the child fragments when the sort order changed!